# JQuery Method Working in Chrome, but not Chrome for Android

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, google-chrome, webkit

This code works great in Chrome desktop:

```
$(window).scroll(function(evt) {
   if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > ($(document).height() - 100)) 
   {
       document.getElementById('mainForm:hiddenRegButton').click();
   }

});
```

However, it never fires in Chrome for Android or Webkit (iOS).  Any ideas why?

Thanks, Graeme.

Comment: Have you tried outputting the values while in `.scroll()`? Also, off-topic: Why do you use `document.getElementById` instead of the jQuery `$`?

Comment: It's strange it's like the numbers are quite right.  Even towards the bottom I get 854 and 1230 for the two separate numbers.  Yeah, I should use the JQuery syntax =)

Answer (score 0):

This is likely to be due to the [multi-threaded compositor on Chrome for Android](http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/impl-side-painting).  To keep scrolling smooth the work is offloaded to the GPU and the GPU only periodically sends it's updated scroll position back to the main thread, often the scroll events will just not fire at all.

This is also similar on iOS.